# Gridview is listing items as Listview, how should i fix it?

Tags: android, gridview, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I am using a custom adapter to get an array from JSONArray and show its contents in a grid view, but gridview is listing the contents as a list view:

ItemsLayout i use as template for items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/flag"
android:layout_width="50sp"
android:layout_height="50sp"
android:layout_marginRight="10sp">
</ImageView>


<TextView
android:id="@+id/pName"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@+id/label"
android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment layout where the gridview is placed in:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product List:"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="351dp"
        android:id="@+id/gvProducts" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:id="@+id/btAdd"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonmain"
        android:textColor="#777777" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Close Cart"
        android:id="@+id/btClose"
        android:backgroundTintMode="src_in"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonmain"
        android:textColor="#777777" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set two properties for your gridView. (hard coded values only for demo)

```
android:columnWidth="60dp"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)